# What is the product flavor for androidTest

Tags: android, unit-testing

The first time, I started to write test cases for Android app, I have searched a lot but could not find the full-phased proper way

Like I am testing Instrumentation Test cases in "androidTest" folder

Below is code for LoginTestCases

```
    @Test
    public void loginUserAccount() {
        NetworkHelper.MOCK_URL = 

        String userName = "abacus@hotmail.com";
        String password = "abacus#112";
        boolean keepMeLoggedInChecked = false;
        boolean touchIdEnabled = false;
        boolean optIn = false;

        mAuthenticationService.logIn(userName, password, keepMeLoggedInChecked, touchIdEnabled, optIn).done(new DoneCallback<LogInResponse>() {
            @Override
            public void onDone(final LogInResponse result) {
                Assert.assertEquals(true,true);
            }
        }).fail(new FailCallback<Throwable>() {
            @Override
            public void onFail(Throwable result) {
                Assert.assertEquals(true,false);
            }
        });
    }
```

For testing I need to change **MOCK_URL value to "/"** so I can implement MockWebServer and choose what response I want, I have used static variable MOCK_URL like below code

```
public class NetworkHelper {
private final OkHttpClient mOkHttpClient;

public static HttpUrl MOCK_URL = null;
public NetworkHelper(OkHttpClient httpClient) {
    mOkHttpClient = httpClient;
}

public Retrofit initialize(String baseUrl) {
    if(MOCK_URL!=null) {
        Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(MOCK_URL)
                .addConverterFactory(JacksonConverterFactory.create())
                .client(mOkHttpClient)
                .build();

        return retrofit;
```

I know that static is not the proper way if anybody knows another way then please give me the solution.

Comment: Shouldn't it be tagged with [tag:android-instrumentation] instead of [tag:unit-testing]?

Comment: @Onik Thanks, done changes